# Can't import torch that could not be resolved

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code take from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5. I installed all the files in requirements.txt, and when I check the pip list, I see the version of torch is available. I tried to run `pip3 install torch` but it announced "Requirement already satisfied". How can I fix this?

```
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # or yolov5n - yolov5x6, custom

# Images
img = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg'  # or file, Path, PIL, OpenCV, numpy, list

# Inference
results = model(img)

# Results
results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
```

Thanks

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied" means that you already have `torch` installed.  So there is nothing to do.

Comment: but when i type "import torch", it still notice that "Import "torch" could not be resolved"

Comment: Can you provide your exact python version?

Comment: my version is 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this with Python are often caused by packages getting installed to the wrong instance of Python.

First off, are you using a virtual environment to run your code? If you are, make sure you're enabling the virtual env when you're installing `torch`.

You can use the following two commands to check if the `pip` you're invoking is from the same instance as where you're running your code. If you're using a virtual environment, make sure you enable it before running the commands.

```bash
pip3 --version
```

and

```bash
python -m pip --version
```

(Depending on your system, you might need to replace `python` with `python3`)

If they don't match, that means you're installing `torch` into the site packages of a different python instance to the one you're running your code in. If you find yourself in this situation, I would carefully look at your `PATH` variable to ensure that your virtual environment is coming first.

Alternatively if you just want to keep moving and the second command reports the correct location/version of python, you can just use `python -m pip install` to install into that virtual env.